# Debugging NullPointerException in a game using multiple sprites and surfaceView

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, sprite

I am a beginner to android and i was trying to make a basic game with the help of an online video tutorial. I am having problem with the multi-sprites and how to use with surfaceview.The application fails launching.
Here is the code of the game.please help me.

```
package com.example.killthemall;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Game extends Activity {

    KhogenView View1;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        while(true){
        try {
            OurThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}

    }
    Thread OurThread;
    int herorows = 4;
    int herocolumns = 3;
    int xpos, ypos;
    int xspeed;
    int yspeed;
    int herowidth;
    int widthnumber = 0;
    int heroheight;
    Rect src;
    Rect dst;
    int round;
    Bitmap bmp1;
    // private Bitmap bmp1;//change name
    public List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>() {
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View1 = new KhogenView(this);
        setContentView(View1);




        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad1));

        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad2));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad3));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad4));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad5));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad6));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good1));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good2));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good3));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good4));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good5));
        sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good6));



    }

    private Sprite createSprite(int image) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image);
        return new Sprite(this, bmp1);
    }

    public class KhogenView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        SurfaceHolder OurHolder;
        Canvas canvas = null;

        Random rnd = new Random();
        {
            xpos = rnd.nextInt(canvas.getWidth() - herowidth)+herowidth;
            ypos = rnd.nextInt(canvas.getHeight() - heroheight)+heroheight;
            xspeed = rnd.nextInt(10 - 5) + 5;
            yspeed = rnd.nextInt(10 - 5) + 5;
        }

        public KhogenView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            OurHolder = getHolder();

            OurThread = new Thread(this);
            OurThread.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            herowidth = bmp1.getWidth() / 3;
            heroheight = bmp1.getHeight() / 4;

            boolean isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning) {
                if (!OurHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;

                canvas = OurHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 50);

                for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {

                    if (widthnumber == 3)
                        widthnumber = 0;
                    update();
                    getdirection();
                    src = new Rect(widthnumber * herowidth, round * heroheight,
                            (widthnumber + 1) * herowidth, (round + 1)* heroheight);

                    dst = new Rect(xpos, ypos, xpos + herowidth, ypos+ heroheight);


                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, src, dst, null);

                }

                widthnumber++;
                OurHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

            }
        }

        public void update() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (xpos + xspeed <= 0)
                xspeed = 40;
            if (xpos >= canvas.getWidth() - herowidth)
                xspeed = -50;
            if (ypos + yspeed <= 0)
                yspeed = 45;
            if (ypos >= canvas.getHeight() - heroheight)
                yspeed = -55;

            xpos = xpos + xspeed;
            ypos = ypos + yspeed;

        }

        public void getdirection() {

            double angleinteger = (Math.atan2(yspeed, xspeed)) / (Math.PI / 2);
            round = (int) (Math.round(angleinteger) + 2) % herorows;
            // Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(round),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public class Sprite {

        Game game;
        private Bitmap bmp;

        public Sprite(Game game, Bitmap bmp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.game = game;
            this.bmp = bmp;


        }

    }

}
```

Here is the logCat if it helps...

```
08-22 23:18:06.980: D/AndroidRuntime(28151): Shutting down VM
08-22 23:18:06.980: W/dalvikvm(28151): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f6f4f0)
08-22 23:18:06.980: D/AndroidRuntime(28151): procName from cmdline: com.example.killthemall
08-22 23:18:06.980: E/AndroidRuntime(28151): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.killthemall
08-22 23:18:06.980: D/AndroidRuntime(28151): file written successfully with content: com.example.killthemall StringBuffer : ;com.example.killthemall
08-22 23:18:06.990: I/Process(28151): Sending signal. PID: 28151 SIG: 9
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.killthemall/com.example.killthemall.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at com.example.killthemall.Game$KhogenView.<init>(Game.java:96)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at com.example.killthemall.Game.onCreate(Game.java:58)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-22 23:18:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(28151):    ... 11 more
08-22 23:18:18.050: D/AndroidRuntime(28191): Shutting down VM
08-22 23:18:18.050: W/dalvikvm(28191): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f6f4f0)
08-22 23:18:18.050: I/Process(28191): Sending signal. PID: 28191 SIG: 9
08-22 23:18:18.050: D/AndroidRuntime(28191): procName from cmdline: com.example.killthemall
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.killthemall
08-22 23:18:18.050: D/AndroidRuntime(28191): file written successfully with content: com.example.killthemall StringBuffer : ;com.example.killthemall
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.killthemall/com.example.killthemall.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at com.example.killthemall.Game$KhogenView.<init>(Game.java:96)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at com.example.killthemall.Game.onCreate(Game.java:58)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-22 23:18:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(28191):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you post your Logcat?

Comment: I think this is your place http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MrEngineer13  Sir, I have included the LogCat. please help me.

Comment: What is on line 96 of Game.java?

Comment: on line 96, I have tried to define the x position of my image through a random co-ordinate which varies from canvas width to the width of the image(herowidth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just letting you know where your issue was I decided to walk you though the debugging process I took so the next time you encounter erroneous exceptions you will better suited to handle them. So the secret to the issue lies inside your LogCat the relevant lines tell us quite a bit:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.killthemall.Game$KhogenView.<init>(Game.java:96)
    at com.example.killthemall.Game.onCreate(Game.java:58)
```

And here is line 96:

```
xpos = rnd.nextInt(canvas.getWidth() - herowidth)+herowidth;
```

Nothing too telling/out of the ordinary here. Now let's check if/how those variables were initialized

First is `xpos`

```
int xpos;
```

That looks fine, now lets look at `canvas`.

```
Canvas canvas = null;
```

And right there is your problem. `canvas` was initialized to *null* two lines before it is used so when you try to call `getWidth()` an exception is thrown; more specifically, a NullPointerException because canvas is pointing to *null* and not a Canvas object.

I'm not sure what exactly you are planning with your app but according to the related [Canvas and Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) documentation they suggest initializing a `Canvas` as such:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
```

Again, I'm not sure of your use-case for `Canvas` but initializing it should get rid of issues with line 96. Hope this helped.